nginx/vite/react config env files to server (without Docker)
I have an application on Vite React, I configured the Nginx file sites/enabled this way (I’m a newbie and this is my first time deploying)
server {
listen 80;
listen \[::\]:80;

server_name example.com;

root /var/www/dist;
index index.html;

location/{
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
}

Routing works, everything is ok, but in the application I also have env files with api

VITE_API="https://########pw/api"
VITE_HOST="https://######.pw"

I use env VITE_API in Axios for each request
import axios from 'axios';

export const $api = axios.create({
baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API,
headers: {
Authorization: `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!)?.accessToken}`,
},
});

$api.interceptors.request.use((config) =\> {
if (config.headers) {
config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!)?.accessToken}` || '';
}
return config;
});

export default $api;

and VITE_HOST in the signal
constructor() {
        this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(`${import.meta.env.VITE_HOST}/NotificationHub`, {
                accessTokenFactory: () => this.getAccessToken(),
                skipNegotiation: true,
                transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
                // transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.ServerSentEvents || signalR.HttpTransportType.LongPolling,
            })
            .withAutomaticReconnect()
            .build();

The question is, how do I add env files so that Nginx understands them? and where ?
Now my request, instead of the ENV API, goes to the server’s IP address and accordingly I receive a response from the server
I have
http://77.232.128.132/Auth/Login and 404 writes
and I need https://a26971-38d9.x.d-f.pw/api/Auth/Login
this code doesn't help
server {
 listen [::]:80;
 server_name example.com;

 root /var/www/dist;
 index index.html;

 location/{
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 }

 location /Auth/Login {
 proxy_pass https://a26971-38d9.x.d-f.pw/api/Auth/Login;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }
}


I understand what you're trying to do is implement some means of configuring your app after it's built, right?
The best way I've found so far is a JSON file fetched via REST client (like Axios) and set up in a React Context.
If you put your config.json in the public folder it will be bundled in the package and you will be able to modify it freely. Nginx will server it as any other file of your app.
From there all you have to do is to fetch it:
export const ConfigContext = React.createContext(undefined);

function App() {

  const [config, setConfig] = React.useState(undefined);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/conf/config.json")
      .then(res => setConfig(res.data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <ConfigContext.Provider value={config}>
      <SomeSubcomponent/>
      (the rest of the app)
    </ConfigContext.Provider>
  );

Once it's done, you use it like this:
import { ConfigContext } from 'path/to/App';

export default function SomeSubcomponent() {
  const config = React.useContext(ConfigContext);
  //remember the config is undefined before the json is fetched
  const host = config?.host;
  //...
}

This is the most generic way with much flexibility - you can swap the Nginx to Spring Boot app and the file could be an endpoint returning a JSON and in the frontend nothing will change. JSON is also not a script so it doesnt require Subresource Integrity verification. It's the most future-proof way I've found so far.

Is there a way to do this without additional code? I'm sure this is somehow configured in Nginx

No, unless you're okay with rebuilding the app every time you change the config. If I understand correctly what those env variables are, they are injected into the code at build time meaning you can't easily change them once the app is built. Meanwhile you can edit the JSON at your leisure, just mind that it could potentially be saved in browser's cache.

ENV are simply not public variables, can’t they be set even in hardcode? or how to do it without them? so that Nginh knows that the API needs to use a specific address on / another?
ENV according to the idea does not have to be changed often, you just put the value and that’s it

everything you put in a frontend app is automatically public, since users can inspect it all - html, css, javascript, networking, all of it.
To me, something like an API base URL is not something that "does not have to ba changed often" - for example they tend to vary e.g. between TEST and PROD.
If you're okay with hardcoding and rebuilding you can just create a src/config.js file and put those addresses in there and import them like any other constant. But this is not an elegant solution.

is there a more elegant solution?

Yes, I've described it in the answer.

But what are the differences if I just launch a react application without specifying the assembly config in the mouth? and using PM 2

what do you mean by "specifying the assembly config in the mouth"? I feel like this is some mistranslation. And what's "PM 2"?

I solved the problem by simply launching the application in the root directory and listening to it through Nginx, adding ENV files to this directory and everything works as it should without root and other settings
server {
location /{
proxy_pass http://localhost:5173;
}
